# how to check if created workflow in sharepoint 2013 as system account

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow, local-system-account

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I just created a survey to which I want to add a workflow, which should send an E-mail confirming the survey response. I created the workflow in SharePoint designer 2013 but it doe not work.
I checked "start automatically" and it is still not working.

1. I've read, that the workflow does not work if it is created by a system account. How do I check if the workflow is created by a system account? (I created the workflow and no virtual machine, so how can it be created by a system account?)
2. If my workflow is created by a system account how can I change that so that my workflow will work?

Thank you in advance for your answer!
Iulia

Answer (score 0):

System Account has created the workflow, that is fine. Just publish the workflow. Hope you have selected to start the workflow automatically when an item is created or changed.

Once you publish it, to test it, you can ask any of the user to respond to the Survey. Make sure, that user has add or edit permission. The workflow will be triggered.

The workflow will not be triggered if the Survey is responded by System Account, which you read earlier.

Just try this and let me know.